# Calculating values in Lua to higher accuracy

Tags: lua, evaluation, calculation, evaluate

The expression `print(math.pi)` gives values of `pi` as `3.1415926535898` up to 13 decimal places on my CPU with `lua 5.3`. Is it possible to get value up to more number of decimal places, for example value of `math.pi` upto 50 decimal places. If so, what would be the highest limit to which it can be calculated in lua?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua uses double precision floating point; the mantissa has 52 bits and so numbers are limited to about 16 decimals.

If you need more precision, use a multiple precision library, such as [lqd](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lqd), which uses quad-double precision with 212 mantissa bits and gives about 64 decimals. Then `qd.pi` gives 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(string.format("%0.50f", math.pi))
```

prints 3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500

From https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lmathlib.c.html

```
#define PI      (l_mathop(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884))
```

Why both numbers differ I don't know. But if you want to print with higher precision than print or tonumber respectively does you have to format the number yourself.

Comment: Despite of format `%0.50f` you have only first 52 bits correct in `math.pi`.